# Pleasantries in questions

Tags: discussion, thanks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

I just saw a question that stated the problem and said 'Thanks in Advance'.  An editor fixed a code block in the question, and also removed the phrase.

Is this an appropriate use of editing?  Leaving a 'thanks' comment after the fact is one thing, but is saying 'thanks' in the question itself really frowned upon?

Comment: Ah, thanks for that link.  I did a search but didn't see that one.  I'll delete this Q. edit: oh, i can't since it has answers, but feel free to close it. sorry. "thanks"!

Comment: why the downvote after its been closed for 1.5 years? **i can't delete this question**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you're in there editing other things then you can clean up the salutations and thanks.  I would never go into a post just to remove them.

See this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: But why remove them at all?

Comment: @Jeff, it doesn't really fit the Q&A aspect of the site.  See the post for much discussion on it.

Comment: @Jeff, as an aside, saying "Thanks" is fine imho. "Thanks in advance" otoh, might mean that you wouldn't bother to say thanks later.

Comment: @Vineet, I think saying thanks is fine in the comments, we just try to keep them out of the posts.

Comment: @Vineet I feel most SO users feel the opposite, if anything.  Saying 'thanks' after the fact creates a superfluous post.  Saying 'thanks' in the question body doesn't. Personally, I'll do either occasionally, but it depends highly on the circumstance

Comment: Oh, perhaps I was wrong...